# Variational Formulation of Yamabe Problem Equivalence.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, curvature

Suppose we have an n-manifold ($M$, $g_0$) with scalar curvature $S_0$. I'm aware that the Yamabe problem can be classed as the problem of minimising the following Einstein-Hilbert Functional over the conformal class of $g_0$.

$$\underset{g \in [g_0]}{\mathcal{E}({g})} =  {\frac{{\int_{\mathcal{M}}{S} {dvol_{{g}}}}}{\left({\int_{\mathcal{M}}dvol_{{g}} }\right)^{{\frac{n-2}{n}}}}}.$$

The metric which minimises this, say $\tilde{g}$, is the metric we're looking for with constant scalar curvature.

All four authors who contributed to the proof of this problem (Yamabe, Trudinger, Aubin, and Schoen) found that this is equivalent to minimising the following functional for $u$.

$$F(u) = {\frac{{\int_{\mathcal{M}}\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}} {\lvert  \nabla u \rvert}^2 + S_0 u^2}{{\| u \|}_p^2}}.$$ and $p=\frac{2n}{n-2}$

The minimising function $\tilde{u}$ then gives our required metric $\tilde{g} = \tilde{u}^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0$ which has constant scalar curvature.

Moreover, the scalar curvature of an arbitrary metric $\tilde{g}$ in $g_0$'s conformal class can be given by

$$\tilde{S} = u^{\frac{-4}{n-2}}\left(S_0 - {\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2}} u^{-1} \mathop{}\!\mathbin\bigtriangleup u\right)$$
where $\mathop{}\!\mathbin\bigtriangleup$ denotes the generalised Laplacian for manifolds.

${\bf Question:}$
How are these two variational problems equivalent? I would imagine it is a simple case of plugging the formula for $\tilde{S}$ into our formula for $\mathcal{E}(\tilde{g})$. However I am unsure how the volume forms transform under this relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a conformal transformation, which means that the volume form transforms as
$$
dvol_{\tilde g} = u^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}vol_{g_0},
$$
and so
$$
\int_Mdvol_{\tilde g} = \int_M u^{\frac{2n}{n-2}}vol_{g_0} = \|u\|_p^p,
$$
with $p=\frac{2n}{n-2}$. By the way I feel that the transformation formula should be $\tilde g=u^{\frac{2}{n-2}}g_0$, not $\tilde g=u^{\frac{4}{n-2}}g_0$.

Comment: Thank you. So if my algebra is correct, the term in the denominator pops out nicely. But in the numerator I have $\int_M \tilde{S}dvol_{\tilde{g}} = \int_M \tilde{S}u^{\frac{2n}{n-2}} dvol_{g_0} = \int_M u^2S_0 -\frac{4(n-1)}{n-2} u\mathop{}\!\mathbin\bigtriangleup u$. Is there some identity I need turn $u\mathop{}\!\mathbin\bigtriangleup u$ into $-{\lvert \nabla \rvert}^{2}$?

Comment: Also, given that in one we are minimising over metrics, and the other we are minimising over functions do I need to account for this? I would assume not given that they have a kind of "positive correlation" relationship if that makes sense ie. small $u$ gives small $\tilde{g}$ and they hit their minimum together?

Comment: @JMill: What you mean is integration by parts (or Green's first identity, or divergence theorem..). For the second question, you are minimizing over the conformal class of metrics, which is by definition the metrics that are positive scalar multiples of each other. So minimizing over this positive scalar function is the same as minimizing over the conformal class of metrics.